# How to retrieve file after modified in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

My friend modified my `.R` file in RStudio and then close RStudio.

Till now, the laptop never been shut down or restart.

Is there any solution can be used to retrieve my origin `.R` file?

Comment: If the file was saved, it overwrote the original file. If not, try using `Save as` and hope for the best. My recommendation would be to use some sort of version control. I like `git`.

Comment: A less technical solution than `git` would be a cloud service like Dropbox or Google Drive that store versions of your files.

Comment: Try opening the file with notepad, if he didn't save it, make a copy. For future cases you may look about [windows shadow copies](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-do-i-configure-and-use-shadow-copy-in-microsoft-windows/)

Comment: (if you're on windows) the counterpart on linux is  using lvm or filesystem  snapshots [related post to get your started](https://serverfault.com/questions/300961/lvm-snapshots-vs-file-system-snapshots)

Comment: @kittygirl From what I know, R Studio doesn't leave a 'backup' file somewhere and the change history is wiped upon closure of rstudio. Sorry

Comment: Maybe check `.history` ?